# Difficulty connecting to database using SQLserver jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to my database using sqljdbc4, I'm pretty new to this so i followed a couple of tutorial but it still doesn't seem to work, When i try to run the program i get this Exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''.        ClientConnectionId:f181fd37-7e28-4392-ac86-02914c2090e1
at  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
```

And this is my code:

```
    try {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBank;","","");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
         }
    return null;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not passing any authentication credentials. If you want to use integrated security (windows authentication), then you need to explicitly specify that in your connection URL **and** you need to load the native library required for this.

See [Connecting with Integrated Authentication On Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated) on Windows on MSDN.

This essentially comes down to including the folder containing the (32 bit or 64 bit) `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in the `java.library.path` system property (see link for details) and adding `integratedSecurity=true` to your connection string:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBank;integratedSecurity=true");
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! i was searching hours for a solution and couldn't understand why it's not working, Working now.

Comment: I was messing around with this for quiet some time.  I was using the driver through Proxool and specifying "integratedSecurity" as a Property which seemed like it should have worked according to the MS docs.  Sure enough, moving to the URL solved the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing empty username and password while connecting to the database in getConnection method:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBank;","","");
```

Try supplying the db username and password, for example:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBank;","myusername","mypassword");
```

Comment: I dont have password and username configured in my database, I've removed the ,"","" , But i still get the same exception